# What is the Probability of Transmission Between Two Nodes in a Neural Network?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs, network, neural-networks

I have a network which is an Erdős–Rényi graph. It is a simple neural network with degree *0.7N* where *N* is the number of nodes.

Each weight between neurons is *$\frac{1}{N}$*, meaning that if node *n* has fired the probability that any connected node *k* will fire in the next time step is *$\frac{1}{N}$* (there is no temporal integration of inputs to any neuron).

My question is as follows. **If node *n* fires at *t=0* what is the probability that a specific node *m* will fire at *t=d* ( *d* time steps later)?**

I know that if the weighted adjacency matrix **W** was a stochastic matrix then the probability would be ${W}_{mn}^{d}$. However the matrix is not stochastic (since the rows do not sum to 1). Furthermore this calculation fails after direct experimentation.

This problem is related to the question: **What is the probability of any path of length *n* between the two nodes in a random graph where the existence of any edge has probability *$\frac{0.7}{N}$*?**

It is most useful if I could do this in terms of **W**. I think the answer may be related to Schur decomposition, as this is alluded to in "*Networks: An Introduction*" by M.E.J. Newman.

Thank you for your help.